# cannot delete the image from the directory but the data succeed deleting from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, delete-file

i cannot delete the image from directory, but the data succeed deleting from database. Please i need help.

Below is the  my controller

```
public function hapus(){

   $id  = $this->input->get('id');

   /* query showing image for deleting image first before delete it from database */
   $path = './asset/uploads/';
   $path1 = './asset/hasil_resize/';
   $arraydelete  = array('id'=>$id);
   $rowdel = $this->Model_upldgbr->get_byimage($arraydelete);

   /* the image delete from folder */
   @unlink($path.$path1.$rowdel->namafile);


   $this->Model_upldgbr->get_delete($arraydelete); 
   $this->session->set_flashdata("pesan", "<div class=\"col-md-12\"><div class=\"alert alert-danger\" id=\"alert\">Success deleting the image and data !!</div></div>");
   redirect('root/upload');


 }
```

And Here is my Model

```
function get_delete($where){
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->delete($this->tabel);
       return TRUE;
    }
//function for showing data one by one from the table
    function get_byimage($where) {
        $this->db->from($this->tabel);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
}
```

Delete Button link is like this :

```
 <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/root/upload/hapus/?id=<?=$row->id?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Comment: `var_dump` the path and check if it's correct

Comment: And why is your `get_delete()` *always* returning TRUE

Comment: use two unlink method for removing from two folders should be like this `@unlink($path.$rowdel->namafile); ` `@unlink($path1.$rowdel->namafile);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

use two `unlink` method for removing file from two folders by using `FCPATH`, should be like this

```
$path = FCPATH.'asset/uploads/';
$path1 = FCPATH.'asset/hasil_resize/';

@unlink($path.$rowdel->namafile); 
@unlink($path1.$rowdel->namafile);

//Or better use ci file helper's `delete_files()` method
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: Thanks dude, it;s really work. thank you for helping me :))

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding , pls do upvote also my answer